# mAP calculation for object detection yolov3

Tags: python, object-detection, python-3.x, yolo

I'm currently working on [yolov3](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) implementation in tensorflow 2.0 and currently I'm working on calculating the [mAP](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173)(mean average precision) scores to evaluate trained models which is a popular metric in measuring the accuracy of object detectors like Faster R-CNN, SSD, yolo, ... Average precision computes the average precision value for recall value over 0 to 1.

Here's an illustrative plot that calculates mAP scores for 30 classes:

[image: map]

31.05 % is calculated by averaging the average precision values for all classes in the model

`(9.32 / 30) * 100 = 31.05%`.

As of my understanding the more the figure, the better and it is a good indicator to rely on when deciding to stop the training / train further.

The question is assuming for example I have a dataset of 2000 images with n bounding boxes and m classes and the validation data will be 0.2 of the dataset size(1600 training examples and 400 validation examples) should I be calculating the map scores on the whole training dataset after each epoch or just take some fraction of it?

I mean to calculate training and validation mAP scores should I make predictions at the end of each epoch and calculate mAP accordingly on 1600, 400 examples respectively? or just take a fraction maybe(100 examples) and predict and calculate on the 100 examples? I'm concerned about efficiency, for example if I'm working with a large dataset, let's say 100k images, wouldn't it be extremely inefficient to make predictions on 100k images after each epoch?

Comment: could you send me your code for mAP